# Trigonometric integrals. Integrate $\int\frac{1}{\cos^4x-\cos^2x\sin^2x+\sin^4x}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried factoring the denominator but does not seem to suit the factorization of quadratic. Is there another way?

Comment: First take notice that your integral is the same as $\int \frac{1}{(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)^2+cos^2 \cdot sin^2 x}$. Can $\sin^2x$ be represented through $\cos$?

Comment: Letting $u=\cos^2 x$ then $\sin^2 x = 1-u$ so $\cos^4-\cos^2x \sin^2 x + \sin^4 x = u^2+u(1-u)+(1-u)^2= 1-u+u^2=1-\cos^2 x +\cos^4 x$. That might be easier to deal with. Then try the $\tan x/2$ substitution, sometimes called the Weierstrass substitution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: Just divide numerator & denominator by $\cos^4x$ and set $\tan x=u$  or by $$\sin^4x$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
 J &= \int \frac{1}{\cos^4 - \cos^2 x \sin^2 x + \sin^4 x} dx \\
   &= \int \frac{\sec^4}{1 - \tan^2 x + \tan^4 x} dx 
\end{align*}

Let $u = \tan x$ and $\sec^2 x = \tan^2 x + 1$

$$ J = \int \frac{(1+\tan^2 x) \sec^2 x}{1- \tan^2 x +\tan^4 x} dx $$

again $ u = \tan x$

$$ J = \int \frac{u^2 + 1}{u^4 - u^2 + 1} du $$

Since $ \int \frac{u^2 + 1}{u^4 - u^2 + 1} du = \arctan(\frac{u}{1-u^2}) + c $

$$ J = -\arctan(2\cot(2x)) + c$$

Comment: Can it be solved by simplifying the equation this way?
$$\frac{1}{cos^4 x-cos^2 x sin^2 x+sin^4x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(cos^2 x)^2-cos^2 x sin^2 x+sin^4x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(1-sin^2x)^2-cos^2 x sin^2 x+sin^4x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1+sin^4x-2sin^2x-cos^2 x sin^2 x+sin^4x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1+2sin^4x-2sin^2x-(1-sin^2x) sin^2 x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1+2sin^4x-2sin^2x- sin^2 x+sin^4x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1+3sin^4x-3sin^2x}\qquad (1)$$ 

$$I=\int \frac{1}{cos^4 x-cos^2 x sin^2 x+sin^4x}dx$$ $$=\int \frac{1}{1+3sin^4x-3sin^2x}$$

Comment: Let $sin^2x=z$ => $2sin xcosxdx=dz$.
But $2sinxcosx$ is not present in the numeratior. What should I do in this case, if I simplify the equation as I have done in step (1)

Comment: @Soumee before you make the substitution multiply numerator and denominator by $\sec^4 x$ and substitute $u \mapsto \tan x$

Comment: @WilmotGray consider marking it as correct if it helped you find a solution (by clicking the green check under the vote number). Glad to help tho!

Comment: Yes sir got it . Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

$$\frac {1}{\cos^4x+\cos^2x\sin^2x+\sin^4x}=$$

$$\frac {1}{(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^2-\cos^2x\sin^2x}=$$
$$\frac {1}{(1+\cos x\sin x)(1-\cos x\sin x)} =$$

$$\frac {1}{2+\sin(2x)}+\frac {1}{2-\sin (2x)}. $$

put $$t =\tan (x)$$
$$\sin (2x)=\frac {2t}{1+t^2} $$
$$dt=(1+t^2)dx $$
 Yes you can finish.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah from $J=\int\frac{u^2+1}{u^4-u^2+1}\mathrm{d}u$       i manipulated it to get $\int\frac{1+\frac{1}{u^2}}{u^2+\frac{1}{u^2}-1}\mathrm{d}u$  now we can rewrite the the denominator as $u^2+\frac{1}{u^2}=\left(u-\frac{1}{u}\right)^2+2$ now putting it back in give me                           $\int\frac{1+\frac{1}{u^2}}{\left(u-\frac{1}{u}\right)^2+1}\mathrm{d}u$ by doing substitution letting $\left(u-\frac{1}{u}\right)=w$   i got the result $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan^2x-1}{\tan x}\right)+c$